# Dynamic variable call on GraphQL - React - Gatsby

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, graphql

I'm actually trying to create a slider in React with some different content through my API that has some different keys to access those contents.

For my graphQL query in my API, I have :

```
title
  excerpt
  nombreDeSlides
  descriptionNode {
    childMarkdownRemark {
      html
    }
  }
  description1Node {
    childMarkdownRemark {
      html
    }
  }
  description2Node {
    childMarkdownRemark {
      html
    }
  }
  description3Node {
    childMarkdownRemark {
      html
    }
  }
```

And I can access it like `data.descriptionNode.childMarkdownRemark.html` but I didn't find a way to change the key "descriptionNode" dynamically to be "description1Node" -- "description2Node" -- ...

I already have my code in a map that get me my variable index to loop, but I really didn't find a way to put the variable index inside my key name.

Answer (score 0):

So, for the moment, I have a solution that does work for some short lists, it works for my case, but I'm still curious about an other solution that implies having a key dynamically.

My solution is to create an array like this one:

```
let htmlArray = [
              data.description1Node.childMarkdownRemark.html,
              data.description2Node.childMarkdownRemark.html,
              data.description3Node.childMarkdownRemark.html,
              data.description4Node.childMarkdownRemark.html,
              data.description5Node.childMarkdownRemark.html,
              data.description6Node.childMarkdownRemark.html
              ];
```

and use the index htmlArray[index] to get the results.

Thank you if you can find me an other solution to this problem I faced.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want all the description nodes for your parent, it might be best if you have a field called `descriptionNodes` that returns an array, allowing you to access child nodes by their index.

```
  title
  excerpt
  nombreDeSlides
  descriptionNodes {
    childMarkdownRemark {
      html
    }
  }
```

Then you can look up the children by their index

```js
data.descriptionNodes[0].childMarkdownRemark.html
```

You could also use [query alias'](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#aliases) combined with a query variable if you really want to keep your object structure, or want to customize a fixed set of 4 slides independently of the parent object.

```
  title
  excerpt
  nombreDeSlides

  descriptionNode(name: $name0) {
    childMarkdownRemark {
      html
    }
  }

  description1Node: descriptionNode(name: $name1) {
    childMarkdownRemark {
      html
    }
  }

  description2Node: descriptionNode(name: $name2) {
    childMarkdownRemark {
      html
    }
  }

  description3Node: descriptionNode(name: $name3) {
    childMarkdownRemark {
      html
    }
  }
```

Also keep in mind GQL queries are just strings, and you can do all sorts of crazy things with them, although I wouldn't recommend it most of the time.

```
title
excerpt
nombreDeSlides

${['', 1, 2, 3].map((node) =>
  `description${node}Node: descriptionNode(name: ${node}) { ...nodeFields }`
).join('\n')}

fragment nodeFields on descriptionNode {
  childMarkdownRemark {
    html
  }
}
```